# SQL i have data without matching and I want to show them all with 0 in cell or blank cell

Tags: sql

I have two tables as shown here:

```
Rate               | soldsale
------             | ----------
keyrate            | keysoldsale
rate               | keyrate
tva                | keyproduct
                   | soldsale
```

I wrote this SQL query:

```
select  
    rate.keyrate, rate.rate, soldsale.keysoldsale, soldsale.keyrate, 
    soldsale.keyproduct,soldsale.soldsale
from
    soldsale, rate
where 
    soldsale.keyrate = rate.keyrate and keyproduct = 20
```

It works well but it didn't show all record of table `RATE`.

For example table rate don't have a sold sale on product it does not shown I want it shown and show it blank or with 0 in cell

Comment: you want an outer join, but that can't be written with the ancient, outdated implicit join conditions in the WHERE clause

Comment: Your doing a kartesian-product, but it sounds like you are after a left join.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes it can.  At least with Oracle, it can (not suggesting we go in that direction).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the question is tagged with `sql` not `oracle` and in standard SQL (which is what the `sql` tag refers to) it's not possible. And even Oracle recommends to not use the `(+)` operator

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sure, that's great.  Your comment said `can't`, which isn't universally true across all RDBMS, hence my comment above :-)

Comment: A LEFT JOIN can be re-written as an old-style, implicit join, with a UNION ALL etc.

Comment: Please tag your request with the DBMS you are using. And you may want to dismiss the teacher  / book  / tutorial that is teaching you to use a join syntax made redundant in 1992.

Comment: left join and outer join and full outer join didn't solve my problem .. thanks

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You wouldn't believe it, but I work with people who still use this syntax.

Comment: @Anis Dev: Then you haven't described the problem well enough. It sounded like there are rates without matching soldsales and you wanted to show them still.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner thats excetly what i want sorry for my bad english

Comment: This is what an outer join does. Tim's query does this. If you think it doesn't, you are mistaken. Maybe you expect data in the table that isn't there? There cannot exist a rate row that Tim's query doesn't show.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I actually think the OP wants an _outer_ join here, but without data I can't be certain (and arguably, using outer join at all might be considered a data smell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join here and move the restriction in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join.

```sql
SELECT
    r.keyrate,
    r.rate,
    s.keysoldsale,
    s.keyrate,
    s.keyproduct,
    s.soldsale
FROM soldsale s
LEFT JOIN rate r
    ON s.keyrate = r.keyrate AND s.keyproduct = 20;
```

Note that the *explicit* join I used above is the preferred way of writing queries these days.  It also makes it easier to see that we are doing a left join.

Comment: still the same result i can't get all record of table rate

Comment: Sample data would be helpful here.

Comment: i have rates without matching soldsales and I want to show them all with 0 in cell or blank cell

Comment: Not helping at all.  Edit your question and include proper input and output.

Comment: Swap the table around. `soldsale s left join rate r`